# work in excel while the macro works, how to perform this task?

Tags: excel, vba

As we know, usually after a macro is run and before **until macro** finishes, we cannot do anything in this excel document.
This is sometimes a little inconvenient, and (*let's imagine*) I do not want to wait for a long time, and it would be nice to do something in the same document in parallel.
Is it possible? If YES, How?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

Excel does not support running macros in a secondary thread, so there's no way to do what you're asking. The reason is pretty clear - how would it work if your macro is doing things on cells that the user can edit/insert/delete while the macro is running, when that can affect the behavior of the macro?

Comment: @UmrbekMatrasulov I agree with Ken here. In fact I mentioned about this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559124/excel-vba-script-stealing-focus#comment107138502_60559124) You could work in a separate Excel Instance but seriously it is still an unreliable way.

Answer (score 0):

No, although there is a potential workaround described in the below link that may be of help.

https://analystcave.com/excel-multithreading-vba-with-vba-worker-threads/

Comment: I went through the article, but there it seems to me a difficult way. My task is not worth such risks :-) thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do something using **Application.ontime**, but you should try not to use macros where it will select cells, sheets, for example: Sheets(1).Activate, Range("A1").Select. Using **Application.ontime** you can do a chronometer for example and continue to select or insert values in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Excel/VBA is definitely NOT a multi-threading technology/solution.  If you have to run several Excel processes in parallel, consider starting one or more new instances of Excel.

```
Opening a second instance of Microsoft Excel causes Windows to load a new copy of the program into memory. This can be useful when you find yourself waiting a long time for Excel to complete complex operations in a large spreadsheet. Opening a second instance of Excel allows you to work with on a different spreadsheet while the first instance of the program is busy.

Desktop View
1.    Open your first instance of Excel, and then right-click the Excel icon on the Desktop taskbar.
2.    Hold down the "Alt" key and select "Excel 2013" from the pop-up menu.
3.    Continue holding down the "Alt" key until you see a prompt asking you if you want to start a new instance of Excel. Click "Yes" to open the new instance.

Start Screen
1.    Open your first instance of Excel, and then right-click the Excel tile on the Start screen.
2.    Hold down the "Alt" key and click "Open New Window" on the Start screen taskbar.
3.    Continue holding down the "Alt" key until you see a prompt asking you if you want to start a new instance of Excel. Click "Yes" to open the new instance.
```

Now, when you open the Task Manager, you see two instances of Excel running.

[image]

You can run these two jobs/tasks in these two instances of Excel, all in parallel!!

Answer (score -1):

Insert DoEvents between your code.

```
Sub test2()

    Do
     '.....

     DoEvents '<~ While the macro is running you can do other things in the Excel document.
    Loop
End Sub
```